# CSS3 Animation Not Working as Expected

Tags: html, css

I cannot get this animation to work for the life in me. It is supposed to move the square from side to side and change the background colour. Other people seem to be using the EXACT same code and getting the desired results. I have tried different supported browsers and even different computers to make sure it wasn't the computer. Any help will be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CSS3 Animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animation.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>CSS3 Animation</h1>
    <div class="square"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.square {
    border: 3px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    clear: both;

    -webkit-animation-name: keyframeMoveDiv;
    animation-name: keyframeMoveDiv;

    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 5s;
    transition-duration: 5s;

    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-timing-function: linear;

    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-direction: alternate;

    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-delay: 2s;

    -webkit-animation-play-state: running; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes keyframeMoveDiv {
    0%   {background:#FF0000; margin-left: 0;}
    25%  {background:#00FF00; margin-left: 200px;}
    50%  {background:#0000FF; margin-left: 500px;}
    75%  {background:#FFFF00; margin-left: 700px;}
    100% {background:#00FFFF; margin-left: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes keyframeMoveDiv {
    0%   {background:#FF0000; margin-left: 0;}
    25%  {background:#00FF00; margin-left: 200px;}
    50%  {background:#0000FF; margin-left: 500px;}
    75%  {background:#FFFF00; marign-left: 700px;}
    100% {background:#00FFFF; margin-left: 0;}
}
```

Comment: So what does your CSS do instead? (i.e. what's the problem you're having)

Comment: @Juhana it increments the border of the square from no border to the 3px border, which isn't even programmed in to do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using this in my css:

```
-webkit-transition-duration: 5s;
transition-duration: 5s;
```

When it needs to be animation duration instead. So:

```
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
animation-duration: 5s;
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/rxoqfhob/)**

```
    .square {
    border: 3px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    clear: both;


    -webkit-animation: keyframeMoveDiv 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: keyframeMoveDiv 5s;


/*    -webkit-animation-name: keyframeMoveDiv;
    animation-name: keyframeMoveDiv;*/

    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

/*    -webkit-transition-duration: 5s;
    transition-duration: 5s;*/

    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-timing-function: linear;

    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-direction: alternate;

    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-delay: 2s;

    -webkit-animation-play-state: running; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes keyframeMoveDiv {
    0%   {background:#FF0000; margin-left: 0;}
    25%  {background:#00FF00; margin-left: 200px;}
    50%  {background:#0000FF; margin-left: 500px;}
    75%  {background:#FFFF00; margin-left: 700px;}
    100% {background:#00FFFF; margin-left: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes keyframeMoveDiv {
    0%   {background:#FF0000; margin-left: 0;}
    25%  {background:#00FF00; margin-left: 200px;}
    50%  {background:#0000FF; margin-left: 500px;}
    75%  {background:#FFFF00; marign-left: 700px;}
    100% {background:#00FFFF; margin-left: 0;}
}
```